# insert data into database after an interval by Java

Tags: java, mysql, javadb

I need to build a program in java which will insert a data into mysql database after every 10 min.And this will continue as long as the user terminates the program. Do I need Thread to build the program? Please suggest references or a block of code that will invoke automatically after every 10 min.

Comment: Use a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: @javalover even though your question was put on hold, you can still accept an answer and/or upvote responses :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the `java.util.concurrent.*` package since it's newer and better for threading (which all timers/delay's will need to implement in order to not block your program)

This example will execute your task, then re-schedule itself automatically... nice! (the try/finally block ensures no exception will break our schedule):

```
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

class Task implements Runnable {

    long untilNextInvocation = 60000; // 1 minute == 60000 milliseconds

    private final ScheduledExecutorService service;

    public Task(ScheduledExecutorService service) {

        this.service = service;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

                // do your stuff here

        } finally {

            service.schedule(new Task(service), untilNextInvocation, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        }

    }

}
```

`UPDATE --`

How to invoke:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // set 3 available threads
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);

    // kick off service
    new Task(service).run();

}
```

OR

You can invoke it from object constructor:

```
public someClassConstructor() {

    // set 3 available threads
    ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);

    // kick off service
    new Task(service).run();

}
```

Comment: That's the basic class I guess, how do I implement in on main as to call this constructor we need a ScheduledExecutorService type object.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [Timer Task](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) for achieving it.

> A task that can be scheduled for one-time or repeated execution by a
>   Timer.